# extend logical volume using parted via script

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, lvm, parted

I would to extend my logical volume via script.

Before i had vm with 10 GB hdd, i incerease hdd 5 GB more, then its toatal 15 GB.
What manually i run command to extend hard disk as follows:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 8388608 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 
Fix/Ignore? fix                                                           
Partition number? 3
End?  [17.2GB]? 100%FREE
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
sudo pvresize /dev/sda3
sudo lvresize --extents +100%FREE --resizefs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

test-vm:~$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               447M     0  447M   0% /dev
tmpfs                               99M  1.1M   98M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  8.8G  4.6G  3.8G  55% /
tmpfs                              491M     0  491M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              491M     0  491M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  106M  804M  12% /boot
/dev/loop1                          72M   72M     0 100% /snap/lxd/16099
/dev/loop2                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21835
/dev/loop3                          44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14295
/dev/loop4                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2253
/dev/loop5                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1270
tmpfs                               99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop7                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2284
/dev/loop8                          44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14549
```

Add extra 5 GB to /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

The above things i would like to run in a script which is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo parted -s /dev/sda 'resizepart 3 100%'

sudo pvresize /dev/sda3

sudo lvresize --extents +100%FREE --resizefs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

while running above script called hdd.sh i am getting below output:

```
test-vm:~ ./hdd.sh 
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 10485760 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 
Error: Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.
  Physical volume "/dev/sda3" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv unchanged from <9.00 GiB (2303 extents).
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem is already 2358272 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

So the very first parted command unable to execute, because i can't provide input 'fix'in the script, tried this
sudo parted -s /dev/sda resizepart 3 Fix '100%'

My goal to extend logical volume via script.
Any input highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's possible to handle this corner case with `parted` in a script (short of re-creating the partition table from scratch).

Unfortunately, `parted` is an interactive program first and scriptable second.

You can use `sgdisk --move-second-header` instead, then continue with `parted` afterwards (or script everything with `sgdisk` if you prefer, but then I don't think `sgdisk` has equivalent for `resizepart`).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your input.

I added as u mentioned sgdisk, then script looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo sgdisk --move-second-header /dev/sda
sudo parted -s /dev/sda 'resizepart 3 100%'

sudo pvresize /dev/sda3

sudo lvresize --extents +100%FREE --resizefs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

And the output of the above script:

```
Warning: The kernel is still using the old partition table.
The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you
run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
The operation has completed successfully.
  Physical volume "/dev/sda3" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv changed from <9.00 GiB (2303 extents) to <14.00 GiB (3583 extents).
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Filesystem at /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 2, new_desc_blocks = 2
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is now 3668992 (4k) blocks long.
```

If i see the df -h i found 5 GB added (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv) after runnning above command :

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               447M     0  447M   0% /dev
tmpfs                               99M  1.1M   98M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   14G  4.6G  8.5G  36% /
tmpfs                              491M     0  491M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              491M     0  491M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  106M  804M  12% /boot
/dev/loop1                          72M   72M     0 100% /snap/lxd/16099
/dev/loop2                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21835
/dev/loop3                          44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14295
/dev/loop4                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2253
/dev/loop5                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1270
tmpfs                               99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop7                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2284
/dev/loop8                          44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14549
```

so i guess only restart needs to be done, or should i need to run other commands ?

thank you!

Comment: Partprobe instead of reboot could work.